# Angular - get server /assets list of files

Tags: angular, file, svg, directory

I want to make sure if there is possibility to list filenames of ~6000 SVG files attached in Angular project /assets sub-folders. (They are available via URL if their name is known), but are not listed if only folder is opened.

I saw similar questions but mentioning rather "local" files, which I understand as user files, not the application.

Answer (score 1):

Angular, as an application running in your browser, does not have access to the file system. You will need to use a backend application which can read the file system and returns the filenames.